# Skrollr Fading out of text

Tags: javascript, html, css, skrollr

I am trying to fade in and fade out a text using skrollr. Below is the code snippet

```
<div id="style" data-100="opacity:0;" data-600="opacity:1;" data-700="opacity:0;">
      Howdy World
 </div>
```

The CSS is as below

```
#style{
    font-size: 80px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
}
```

The fade in and fade out is working as expected. But the text is not aligned to the center.
Should I use Position with data attributes to achieve this or where am I am i going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have applied "position: fixed" to the div, it will be rendered in absolute positioning. So you need to set the "width" to 100% if you want to align the text on the document.

```
 #style{
   font-size: 80px;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
 }
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ug5CH/)

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: @Chikenrice Modifying the width to 100% help me. Also tried the solution provided below. Both provides the expected output. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use data attributes for achieve this.

I have crated JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/anjum121/zkym4/

```
<div id="style" data-100="opacity:0; left:25%;"  data-600="opacity:1;left:25%;" data-700="opacity:0;left:25%;" >
  Howdy World
```

Comment: I tried using the left attributes with percentage.It worked like charm.I have a clarification about the 25% will this be same as aligning to center or is it like moving the div to position 25% towards right from left side of screen.